# How to generate sequence number in Redis?

Tags: redis

I need a sequence of numbers generated by the Redis server.
Something like abc:**20160912**185342000000000123
Here, the numbers in bold is the current date and the remaining numbers are the sequence number provided by redis.

Comment: You can wrap the logic of concatenating date and number into a lua script

Answer (score 2):

A Lua script to achieve this could look like:

```
eval "local count = redis.call('incr','sequence_number')\n return ARGV[1] .. ':' .. ARGV[2] .. count" 0 abc 20160912
```

This assumes the sequence number will be stored in a key named `sequence_number` and will be incremented by one each time you evaluate this script. If sequence_number does not exist it will be created and its initial value will be 1.

You have to provide the current date and the prefix string when calling  EVAL. It doesn't seem you can call os.date in a Redis Lua script.

As usual with Redis Lua scripts, you can avoid a systematic evaluation of the script by using EVALSHA to send the SHA1 of the string representing the Lua script. You send the whole script using EVAL only when EVALSHA fails (it means the script is not cached in Redis).

Answer (score 1):

Redis can't do this *per se*. There're two options here to solve the issue:

1. A *Lua script*.
2. A generator in your application layer.